# Getting feature names from Logistic Regression model in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to get the features names from my logistic regression model in spark.

Not sure how to do this

here is my code

```
lr = LogisticRegression(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", maxIter=10)
lrModel = lr.fit(trainingData)
lrPredictions = lrModel.transform(testData)
lrCv = CrossValidator(estimator=lr, estimatorParamMaps=lrParamGrid, evaluator=evaluator, numFolds=2)
lrCvModel = lrCv.fit(trainingData)
```

This is what I have attempted

```
lr.summary._call_java('featuresCol')
#returns the error: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'summary'
lrCvModel.summary._java_obj.getFeaturesCol()
#returns error: AttributeError: 'CrossValidatorModel' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try accessing the bestModel ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel.bestModel)) summary:

`lrCvModel.bestModel.summary`

or LogisticRegressionModel summary ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.summary))

`lrModel.summary`